# How to write an arrow xdashmapsto?

Tags: arrows

This is a continuation of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45967/there-is-a-need-for-at-least-two-more-dashed-arrows-in-amssymbols-how-to-pro) about arrows needed for birational geometry, with the same basic premise as [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136772/dotted-or-dashed-xrightarrow/136777#136777) about `xdashrightarrow` etc.

I need an arrow like `xmapsto` but with the `mapsto` arrow dashed. I currently have

```
\def\dashmapsto{\mapstochar\dashrightarrow}
```

which gives the `dashmapsto` arrow. I would love it if I could have a `xdashmapsto` to go with it.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just combined the two answers that you cite, using David's technique applied to Heiko's code.  The credit goes to them.  Here was my addition to Heiko's code:

```
\newcommand\xdashmapsto[2][]{\mathrel{\mapstochar\xdashrightarrow[#1]{#2}}}
```

The only twist was to remember to employ arguments in the same manner as employed by `\xdashrightarrow`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\xdashmapsto[2][]{\mathrel{\mapstochar\xdashrightarrow[#1]{#2}}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\da@rightarrow}{\mathchar"0\hexnumber@\symAMSa 4B }
\newcommand*{\da@leftarrow}{\mathchar"0\hexnumber@\symAMSa 4C }
\newcommand*{\xdashrightarrow}[2][]{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette{\da@xarrow{#1}{#2}{}\da@rightarrow{\,}{}}{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\xdashleftarrow}[2][]{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette{\da@xarrow{#1}{#2}\da@leftarrow{}{}{\,}}{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\da@xarrow}[7]{%
  % #1: below
  % #2: above
  % #3: arrow left
  % #4: arrow right
  % #5: space left 
  % #6: space right
  % #7: math style 
  \sbox0{$\ifx#7\scriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle\else\scriptstyle\fi#5#1#6\m@th$}%
  \sbox2{$\ifx#7\scriptstyle\scriptscriptstyle\else\scriptstyle\fi#5#2#6\m@th$}%
  \sbox4{$#7\dabar@\m@th$}%
  \dimen@=\wd0 %
  \ifdim\wd2 >\dimen@
    \dimen@=\wd2 %   
  \fi
  \count@=2 %
  \def\da@bars{\dabar@\dabar@}%
  \@whiledim\count@\wd4<\dimen@\do{%
    \advance\count@\@ne
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\da@bars\expandafter{%
      \da@bars
      \dabar@ 
    }%
  }%  
  \mathrel{#3}%
  \mathrel{%   
    \mathop{\da@bars}\limits
    \ifx\\#1\\%
    \else
      _{\copy0}%
    \fi
    \ifx\\#2\\%
    \else
      ^{\copy2}%
    \fi
  }%   
  \mathrel{#4}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[ X \xdashmapsto{x} Y \xdashmapsto{\mathrm{longer}} Z 
\xdashmapsto[\mathrm{underset}]{\mathrm{longer}} W 
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If one finds the spacing after the arrow too great, it could be redefined with a small negative space as

```
\newcommand\xdashmapsto[2][]{\mathrel{\mapstochar\xdashrightarrow[#1]{#2}\!}}
```

Comment: Ok that seems obvious now! Thanks very much.